# SecureCRT vertical scroll speed using Trackpad is too fast on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, vertical-scrolling, trackpad, secure-crt

I am using an early 2011 MacBook Pro and have recently installed SecureCRT.
I was previously using an old 2006 model but the problem at hand was not present with my old machine.
Both machines running OSX Yosemite 10.10.1.

When viewing any session in SecureCRT, the vertical scroll speed when using the trackpad is insanely fast.  I have checked my System Preferences and the vertical scroll speed is normal when using browsers, text editors, pdf viewers etc.

There are no apparent settings within SecureCRT to manipulate the vertical trackpad scroll speed, yet I question why this only affects this application.

I have posted a question to the VanDyke forums but to no avail have I received an answer just yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this juiced up scroll speed is slowing my work efficiency.

Comment: EDIT: Have since received a response from someone at Van Dyke.  The forum thread can be followed here: https://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=11822

Answer (score 0):

The trackpad speed issue is related to the version of SecureCRT and the version of OSX.

I have been running SecureCRT v6.6 on OSX Yosemite 10.10.1 on the new machine and it is surprising that I can even load the application without crashing as there should be a Python Library mismatch.

> VanDyke Rep: "For one, I am not sure how you are running SecureCRT v6.6 on Yosemite at all. The first version to officially support Yosemite is 7.3.x. To my recollection, running anything much older than v7.2 would cause crashes due to a Python library mismatch."

I have upgraded SecureCRT to version 7 and trackpad scroll speed is back to normal.